# Radius of convergence of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)^{2n}}{2^n n^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

My Attempt :
$$a_{2n}=\frac{1}{2^{n}n^{3}}$$

But Root Test gives $$a_{2n}^{1/2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and Ratio Test gives $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{2}$$
So What is ROC $\mathbf{✓2 \;or\; 2}$

Comment: Why it's $$a_{2n}$$  not $$a_n?$$

Comment: Power is 2n. you may take n or put 2n= u and solve it will nake mo difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define
$$
a_n : = \frac{{(x - 1)^{2n} }}{{2^n n^3 }}.
$$
Then
$$
\sqrt[n]{{a_n }} = \frac{{(x - 1)^2 }}{{2n^{3/n} }} \to \frac{{(x - 1)^2 }}{2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{{a_{n + 1} }}{{a_n }} = \frac{{(x - 1)^2 n^3 }}{{2(n + 1)^3 }} \to \frac{{(x - 1)^2 }}{2}.
$$
Thus, by either the root or the ratio test, the series is convergent when
$$
\frac{{(x - 1)^2 }}{2} < 1 \Leftrightarrow \left| {x - 1} \right| < \sqrt 2 .
$$

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the power series is given by

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)^{2n}}{2^n 3^n}.$$

The root test leads to

$$\frac{(x-1)^2}{6}<1,$$

hence

$$|x-1| < \sqrt{6}.$$

Comment: Sorry I edited my question... Now I got confused..

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\dfrac{|x-1|^{2n}}{(2\cdot3)^n}=$

$\sum \left (\dfrac{|x-1|}{√6}\right )^{2n}$.

Converges for $\dfrac{|x-1|}{√6}<1$.

Comment: I edited my question Now I got confused..

Comment: Separate question: $y:=x-1$; then $\frac{(y^2/2)^n}{n^3}$; For $(y^2/2) \le 1$ convergent.For $(y^2/2)>1$ divergent(power grows faster than $n^3$).

Answer (score 1):

The ratio formula cannot be applied here since

- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)^{2n}}{2^n n^3} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k(x-1)^k$ with
  $$a_{2l+1}=0 \text{ and } a_{2l}=\frac 1{2^ll^3} \text{ for } l \in \mathbb{N} $$

So, the quotient $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ is either $0$ or undefined.

But with the root formula there is no problem:

$$R = \frac 1{\limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}} = \frac 1{\lim_{l\to\infty} \sqrt[2l]{a_{2l}}} =  \lim_{l\to\infty} (\sqrt 2 \sqrt[2l]{l^3})=\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

To apply the ratio test for the series, we do this:
$$
\frac{(x-1)^{2n+2}/2^{n+1} (n+1)^3}{(x-1)^{2n}/2^n n^3}
=\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\;\cdot\;\frac{n^3}{(n+1)^3} \to \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}
$$
Thus we have convergence if
$$
\left|\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\right| < 1 
\Longleftrightarrow
|(x-1)^2| < 2
\Longleftrightarrow
|x-1| < \sqrt2
$$
Similarly we have divergence if $|x-1| > \sqrt{2}$.  As usual, the ratio text is inconclusive when $|x-1| = \sqrt2$.

Comment: Now I got it... Thanks